# Can I use custom java class library with ionic framework?

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code

I am working with a Mobile Application project on **ionic framework 3.19.0 with VS Code for Android platform**. Where I want to execute few activities like download a apk file from web, checksum validation etc using custom Java Library prepared by other team.

I have searched a bit but not yet getting any suitable guideline or tutorial regarding these issues.

**Is it possible to integrate Java Library with ionic and use it's class /function etc or is there other way exist?**

Can anybody help ?

**Edit:**
There are few built in plug-in available for application version check and update (**App Update, App Version**) activities . Check [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-version/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to develop a cordova plugin if you want to interact with a native android library, can't be done directly through ionic. 
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html